# Obtain the valueField from combo after to set displayValue?? EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I have a problem in getting the number value to the combobox.

```
{
    xtype: "combo",
    name: "cmb_scc",
    id: "cmb_scc",
    hiddenName: "combovalue",
    fieldLabel: "SCC",
    width: 305,
    store: store_SCC,
    valueField: 'subcentro_codigo',
    displayField: 'subcentro_nombre',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    disabled: true,
    mode: 'local',
    readOnly: false,
    allowBlank: false,
    listeners:{
        select: function(combo, record, index) {
            Ext.getCmp("cmb_scc").setValue(record.get('subcentro_nombre'));
        }
    } 
},
```

In this combobox I have 2 values, the `valueField` and `displayField` obtained from the store_SCC. These values can be for example:

1 - Engineering,
2 - Humanity 
... etc.

When I click the combo show the name ( Engineering) that depends of the number value (1).

This name is showed when I setValue with:

```
Ext.getCmp("cmb_scc").setValue(record.get('subcentro_nombre'));
```

But this line replaces the original value 1 of 'cmb_scc' to text Engineering, if I want  to obtain the number value from the field after, it is not possible, but I can only obtain this number value if I  call `getValue` method before that line.

Example (subcentro = 1):

```
var subcentro = form_nuevoContrato.getForm().findField('cmb_scc').getValue();

Ext.getCmp("cmb_scc").setValue(record.get('subcentro_nombre'));
```

Example (subcentro = Engineering)

```
Ext.getCmp("cmb_scc").setValue(record.get('subcentro_nombre'));

var subcentro = form_nuevoContrato.getForm().findField('cmb_scc').getValue();
```

How can I obtain the number value from the combo after to setValue in combo? I need to use it in other statements later, like to fill a grid that depends of the number value from cmb_scc.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried setting the record itself as the value? `setValue(record)`. It should return the `valueField` value even with your code. You can call `getSubmitValue()` though. Could you provide us with a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/)?

Comment: The point of the combo is that the value is driven by the `valueField`, the `displayField` is only used for what the name implies. If you already have the record, you have both values to begin with.